# How do I enable error reporting in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

I recently moved my site from a shared server to my own server. Now, when I have a PHP error, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. At my old host, I'd get something like "Fatal error: Expecting ;". How do I enable that?

Comment: Related: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Comment: It may be a duplicate but it's number 1 on google and I'm pretty sure I visit this page at least once a week. One of these days I'll save a snippet...