# Show Header error on localhost

Tags: php, http-headers

When I uploaded my site to the server I got these errors.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/j/o/u/jou/html/biggydaddy/wp-config.php:25) in /home/content/j/o/u/jou/html/biggydaddy/wp-login.php on line 12

I understand the reasons behind them, but in my localhost this warning not shown.

How do I display those errors?

Comment: make sure you have configure the site well and plz share the site url

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How do I enable error reporting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting)

Comment: What are you using for your server on your computer? (MAMP, WAMP, XAMPP, etc.)

Comment: I have been receiving this same error on an actual server, but not on my localhost. Error reporting has been turned on etc, I found out where it was but would love to have this displayed locally if anyone knows... (This was using XAMPP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)This error comes when you print any thing before php hreader command

Please check for any `echo or print / print_r .. (or may be White Space)` 
2)
You need to set both [**error_reporting**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [**display_errors**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors). These can be set in php.ini, in Apache (if you're using PHP as an Apache module) or during run-time, though if you set it during run-time then it won't effect some types of errors, such as parse errors.

Comment: error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT and display_errors = On also restarted Apache still no warning..

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have set output_buffering=Off 
for showing error on localhost you have to set output_buffering=Off in your php.ini file and then restart your XAMPP .....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the file mentioned (`/home/content/j/o/u/jou/html/biggydaddy/wp-config.php`) and make sure nothing is being output from there. This could be as simple as an extra space before the opening `<?php` tag.

In my Wordpress config file that line is the DB password. Make sure that you haven't got any characters there like an extra unescaped quote that could cause problems.

Comment: I know some text before header file my problem is how we display those errors in my localhost it's visible on myhosted server

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's some space characters after the final `?>` in a PHP file.

Comment: Do you mean whitespace *before a PHP `header()` function call*? It has nothing to do with whitespace after the final `?>`. In fact you can put anything after that. :)

Comment: I know some text before header file my problem is how we display those errors in my localhost it's visible on myhosted server

Comment: Of course you can. But if you have output before a call to the header function, the afore mentioned error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using wordpress  then set WP_DEBUG constant to true in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Or if for normal php script set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not using wordpress and i set (error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);) also getting other errors and notices but not this one