# Turn on all header's error and warnings in PHP

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have followed lots of tutorials having the links below and tried almost all.

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings)

[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

[LINK 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304868/show-header-error-on-localhost)

[LINK 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708187/on-localhost-redirect-works-on-hostgator-error-cannot-modify-header-information)

The problem in my situation is when I upload my files to a server it shows lots of `header already send` errors on server but there is such error on `localhost`.
I am using `godaddy`'s server and on localhost using `Wamp` server

I have tried this code also

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It's also failing (NO errors NO warnings).

**What I want to show all errors and warnings so that when I upload my files on server all error vanish.**

I'm struggling with over hundred errors.  Please help.

---

As I mentioned I tried the duplicate answer link also but its not working. So if you can't help let others to help me

Comment: hey i told you i tried this link and isn't working

Comment: You should post some code then and not links to tutorials that you've tried. If anything, this should either remain closed or closed as it lacks sufficient info to diagnose the problem.