# Uploadify missing out file extension

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm using uploadify on web project, and I'm not particularly a php whizz so am struggling to see why the following results in an uploaded image without a valid extension. I get '1-profile' without the .jpg extension. Can anybody shed any light?

```
    <?php
/*
UploadiFive
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
*/

// Set the uplaod directory
$uploadDir = '/img/profiles/';

// Set the allowed file extensions
$fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'); // Allowed file extensions

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {

    rename($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], $_POST['user_id'].'-profile');

    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;

    $targetFile = $uploadDir .$_POST['user_id']. '-profile.'. strtolower($fileParts['extension']);

    // Validate the filetype
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']), $fileTypes)) {

        // Save the file
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
        echo 1;

    } else {

        // The file type wasn't allowed
        echo 'Invalid file type.';

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You say that you're getting `1-image` with no extension yet the code you provided wouldn't remotely create that file name, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Sorry - I mean't 1-profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referencing `$fileParts` before it is defined?

```
$targetFile = $uploadDir .$_POST['user_id']. '-profile.'. strtolower($fileParts['extension']);

// Validate the filetype
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
```

should be

```
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$targetFile = $uploadDir .$_POST['user_id']. '-profile.'. strtolower($fileParts['extension']);

// Validate the filetype
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, but I couldn't see it! :)

Comment: PHP would've thrown a warning about this. You might want to turn on error reporting on your development machine to make these problems easier to debug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting