# Recursive File listing stops after 2 files

Tags: php, recursion, foreach, iteration, file-listing

I have the following code to list all files (in the direct folder and sub folders).

```
$imagesDir = '../Stock_Images';
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($imagesDir);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file)
{
    echo $file->getPathname() . '<br/>';
}
```

The problem is that I have 2 files named ".apdisk" and ".DS_Store".
The script list both of the files and then stops like there's a bug or something.
I deleted one of the files and then it worked as it should....

Any idea why it happens and how to fix that?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I also had FOLDER named ".TemporaryItems" < dont ask me why.
It was the problem >

```
Caught exception: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(../Stock_Images/.TemporaryItems/folders.501): failed to open dir: Permission denied
```

just deleted that folder and it fixed the problem.

Comment: [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting) and tell us if there is any errors

Comment: but you just said that you had two files there. it would have to stop no? I'm sure I'm missing something. Did you try getting a try/catch block around the foreach, just to check?

Comment: @marco I have 2 files with just extension in their name. The rest are regular.

Comment: @Ron the try/catch is always a good starting point.