# unable to use variables defined in class

Tags: php, import, global-variables

Hi i am trying to import the configuration variables from a config file that i had created

***Config.php*** has

```
class Config
{
    public $SERVERNAME = '*******';
    public $SUSERNAME = '*********';
    public $SPASSWORD = '*********';
    public $DBNAME2 = '********';
}
```

for importing this variable in another file i tried

```
include('./Config.php') or die("error");
$cnfig = new Config();
```

But when i try to use `$cnfig->DBNAME2` its not working

Please help to sole this problem.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

It was working in localsystem , when i tied to upload through web hosting it was not working.

Comment: Can you print `echo "<pre>";print_r($cnfig);`?

Comment: No.Lines after defining objects were not executed...!

Comment: Why don't you just use `require`? Using the return value from `include` can be tricky.

Comment: when i use require(), the lines after calling the require() was not working

Comment: i cant get you jeroen.

Comment: Either the file gets included successfully or execution stops.

Comment: so what can i do at this point to make it work.I have been breaking my head with this for past 4 hour.Could you please help me to sort the way?

Comment: Check the path, make sure it is correct as the file cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
include  ('./Config.php');
$cnfig = new Config();
echo "<pre>";print_r($cnfig);
```

**Edit:**

I am getting below output so it should be working for you too.

```
Config Object
(
    [SERVERNAME] => *******
    [SUSERNAME] => *********
    [SPASSWORD] => *********
    [DBNAME2] => ********
)
```

**Edit:2**

You can also do like this

```
(include('./Config.php')) or die("error");
$cnfig = new Config();
echo "<pre>";print_r($cnfig);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#39043

`or` has higher priority than `include()`

**Error Ouput:**

When only use `include('./Config.php') or die("error");` it's giving below error.

---

Warning: include(1) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\path_to_file\myConfig.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '1' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library') in D:\path_to_file\myConfig.php on line 2

Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in D:\path_to_file\myConfig.php on line 6

Comment: Tried,this was also not printing anything.

Comment: That was the problem,what is working for every one was not working for me.

Comment: even Edit:2 gives same result.

Comment: Above should work because your code `include('./Config.php') or die("error");` is giving error.

Comment: when i remove $cnfig = new Config(); all lines below it started working.So problem is there for only declaring the object.

Comment: With your original code, Are you not getting any error message when you try to include your Config.php file?`

Comment: You should get error message. Try to put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page.

Comment: Then there should be some other things going on. Because above solution should work as first I was getting error with your original code but then I corrected code and posted as answer and same must be worked for you.

Comment: was it good to directly specify DB username/password in connect statement without importing any variables?

Comment: You should use `PDO` like `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=YourHost;dbname=YourDBName", "YourUserName", "YourPassword");` but we your're using mysql_*() then `mysql_connect("YourHost", "YourUserName", "YourPassword");` But mysql_*() are strongly discouraged and they are deprecated.

Comment: ok,if the files were in same folder then the path which i gave was correct or need to be changed?

Comment: File inclusion path is Correct

Comment: ok,then i will go with directly specifying the parameters instead of getting from a global variable.And Thank you all for taking time to solve my problem.

Comment: just now i found even if i specify wrong path or file name in include it does not shows error.so there are some basically some problems.I need to find whats causing that.

Comment: To know more about How to display error? Visit this SO(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting) link