# php isn't giving any error in output

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have apache2 installed on my PC.
And php5 and all the stuffs. 
The php is also running fine. I checked commands `INSERT INTO myTable` etc and it's working fine.
I've phpMyAdmin installed and it's also working fine.
The problem is that I'm not getting any error when there is actually error.
for e.g.
PHP :

```
<?php
  <?php
  $umair = 1

  echo $umair;
  echo 'asdf';
?>
```

This code isn't outputting anything. As you can see there is error of semicolon here and the PHP must show some error.
And if I put the semicolon then the PHP runs as usual and get the output `1asdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `php.ini` settings to display errors :

```
- error_reporting to E_ALL
- display_errors to on
```

(those are developement environment settings of course ; [more about error_reporting levels here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php))

You can find your `php.ini` location using `phpinfo()` in a PHP script.

**EDIT** In case it isn't that, try to execute a valid script, and tell us if it runs correctly. If it doesn't, it probably means that your php module installation failed somehow.

**EDIT 2** Restarting Apache will be necessary after editing such parameters.

Comment: I'm not inclined to believe, that error reporting can salvage the problem

Comment: It most probably can.

Comment: In a debug situation, I suggest setting these parameters to a value that will display as much as possible. There wouldn't be any need of displaying errors with a 0 reporting level on the server, for instance.

Comment: @Cthulhu The errors shown by OP, are should pretty much be displayed,  dispite the error reporting directives

Comment: Well let's see how it turns out.

Comment: Could you edit your post and paste the last lines of your Apache logs ? (error.log and access.log) No output could be an incomplete answer from the server.

Comment: Oh Actually it worked. I just needed to restart the apache server.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show the errors for the current file that you're working on right now by adding

```js
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and try to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the missing ";" is a parser error - and parsing is done before execution. 
PHP will simply not even start executing an invalid script - so you don't see anything.

Try to include this script in another script and run that - then you will get a clear error-msg!

Here's more on that topic and also my script to do this: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/17555172#17555172)