# How to call php function with javascript function in Jquery Easy UI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I get the problem to create custom autonumber in dialog form jquery easy ui..

I Have the a function in controller like this..

```
public function getCode()
{
    if(!isset($_POST))  
        show_404();

    $query = "SELECT MAX(kode_barang) as maxID FROM tb_barang";
    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
    $data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
    $idMax = $data['maxID'];
    $noUrut = (int) substr($idMax, 1, 4);
    $noUrut++;
    $newID = "B" . sprintf("%04s", $noUrut);
    $queryData  = $query->row_array();
    $phpVar     = array( "STATUS" => $newID); 
    echo json_encode ($phpVar) ;    
}
```

and I call that function from view, the javascript function like this..

```
<script> function makeAjaxCall()
{ 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        data: $('#form').serialize(), 
        url: "http://192.168.0.77/ci_jquery/barang/getCode", 
        cache: false,   
        success: function(json){        
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json); 
        var r = obj['STATUS'];
        document.forms["form"]["kode_barang"].value = r;
    } 
});
} 
</script>
```

And this is my dialog form.

```
<div id="dialog-form" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:300px; height:400px; padding: 10px 20px" closed="true" buttons="#dialog-buttons">
    <form id="form" method="post" novalidate>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <div class="form-item">
                <td width="100"><label for="type">Kode Barang </font></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kode_barang"/></td>
            </tr>
</div>
```

Thanks for reply and attention.

Comment: Ok - and your question is?

Comment: Start with basic debugging: check the values in your POST request, and the values being returned by your PHP script. Make sure you're getting what you expect to get. That will pin down where the problem is in your code.

Comment: I think my simple problem is how to create autonumber in jquery easy ui.. :) Actually i m not post a variable, i just want get value from $query = "SELECT MAX(kode_barang) as maxID FROM tb_barang";

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `getCode()` function fails. You are using the `$query` as an object however it is just a string..

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(kode_barang) as maxID FROM tb_barang";
$queryData  = $query->row_array();
```

You should be getting an error saying that you are calling `row_array()` on a non-object. You should remove this line as it is not even used.

You should at least test your PHP code before using it with any other scripts/functions. This is in addition to [turning error reporting on in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php) in your development environment to show things like this.

Comment: I dont understand to debug with your suggest, usually i find debug with echo and alert :p.. thanks for reply immulatin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
You can do this by using jquery Ajax in your javascript function.
Set url parameter in ajax with file and function name.
```

-

Thanks