# INSERT INTO prepared statement failure

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=members', 'user', 'password');
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Error :' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO mfb_members('',FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,Bday,Bmonth,Byear) VALUES(:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password,:birth_day,:birth_month,:birth_year)';
$response = $db->prepare($sql);
$response->execute(array(
        'first_name'=>$first_name,
        'last_name'=>$last_name,
        'email'=>$email,
        'password'=>$password,
        'birth_day'=>$birth_day,
        'birth_month'=>$birth_month,
        'birth_year'=>$birth_year,
));
```

Hello, it's been hours i'm trying to figure out whats wrong. The problem I have is that when I type in the .php file the prepared statement, the page on my website appears blank. I just can't figure how to send the filled-in form (users need to fill in a subscription form) to my database ?

Comment: alert statement **response** what you get actual output there

Comment: Have you got error reporting enabled? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: nope I have no error being reported, just all blank.

Comment: Enable error reporting and see what the error is. Also check the error log.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging and looking into logs / at error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a blank page because the script throws an error and you do not have error reporting enabled. It's probably the query, that is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO mfb_members('',FirstName
                        ^^
               error in SQL statement
```

Comment: Using it as a column name?

Comment: Thanks fab! the error was coming from it, since there were no correspondence in the VALUES().

Answer (score 0):

i think the erro is `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`, there're 8 columns and 7 values, remove the **''**