# In PHP, why won't this write to test.txt?

Tags: php, file, fwrite

My code is

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('test.txt', "a+");
fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase mice');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

but test.txt is still empty. I don't see anything wrong and I don't understand why it's not writing.

Comment: What does `error_reporting` say?

Comment: The first thing you should do is check if the file is writable with `is_writable()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Comment: File permissions issue. Add `chmod 0777` in your code or `chmod 777` directly on server via FTP.

Comment: I check if it's writable, and it says it isn't. The files exists, how would I make it writable?

Comment: which web server and what operating system ?

Comment: If you remove the file, will it be created with your script?

Comment: Thanks Anders, that was the problem. Thanks for solving EDIT: I can't answer my won question, would someone mind doing it? It was a file permission error, command to fix it was chmod a+w test.txt

Comment: A solution was found and that's the important thing @AndersLindén cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write this in a console

```
chmod a+w test.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a file permissions issue.

This will chmod your file to `777` making it writeable.

Tested on Linux server:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('test.txt', "a+");
chmod("test.txt", 0777); // try also 0666 or 0644
fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase mice');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

You can also use `0666` or `0644` depending on how high a permission you wish the file to have, yet `0644` would be your safest option; see below.

You can also type in `chmod 777 test.txt` or `chmod 666 test.txt` or `chmod 644 test.txt` via FTP.

My server let's me use `0644` to write and append to and may be different on the server you are wanting to execute your code.

---

Quoted from http://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-gsg-en-7.2/s1-navigating-chmodnum.html

**Beware 666 and 777**

Setting permissions to 666 or 777 will allow everyone to read and write to a file or directory.

These permissions could allow tampering with sensitive files, so in general, it is not a good idea to use these settings.

Here is a list of some common settings, numerical values and their meanings:

```
-rw------- (600) — Only the owner has read and write permissions.

-rw-r--r-- (644) — Only the owner has read and write permissions; the group and others can read only.

-rwx------ (700) — Only the owner has read, write and execute permissions.

-rwxr-xr-x (755) — The owner has read, write and execute permissions; the group and others can only read and execute.

-rwx--x--x (711) — The owner has read, write and execute permissions; the group and others can only execute.

-rw-rw-rw- (666) — Everyone can read and write to the file. (Be careful with these permissions.)

-rwxrwxrwx (777) — Everyone can read, write and execute. (Again, this permissions setting can be hazardous.)
```

Here are some common settings for directories:

```
drwx------ (700) — Only the user can read, write in this directory.

drwxr-xr-x (755) — Everyone can read the directory, but its contents can only be changed by the user.
```

Comment: What do you mean? @AndersLindén

Comment: 0666 can be used if you dont want to execute the file

Comment: True, it can be `0644` which works on my server, however it may not be the case with the OP. @AndersLindén

Comment: I used `chmod a+w test.txt`, that works, but these others may have worked as well. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You're welcome, just glad you found a solution. @user3053417 Please accept [Anders' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20307421/1415724) to close the question, cheers.

Comment: Click on the white checkmark till it turns green in [Anders' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20307421/1415724) to give rep points because it solved your problem. If not, your question will remain in the unanswered category. @user3053417