# Getting blank page when uploading an image in Laravel

Tags: php, image, error-handling, upload

I have a question that concerns an image upload in one of my applications.

I have the issue that if I want to upload a picture that I have exported from iPhoto, the image is not uploaded and I only get a blank page instead. Sometimes I also receive a 500 error in the console.

The awkward thing about this is that images taken from the web and screenshots for example work perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea on this topic? Would really appreciate some thoughts here or ways in PHP to fix something like that.

Comment: My first guess is that error reporting is off?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Comment: never turned that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be a max file size issue, or even a memory issue.

I think you might get a blank screen also if there is a PHP error, with debugging turned off.

Check your script execution time, PHP memory, and max file upload in your php.ini

If smaller images work I suspect is an issue with larger photos.

Comment: what exactely is the php.ini? Since I work with laravel I have a config folder that contains all the appliation configurations. I dont remeber me setting up any settings concerning pictures...

Comment: php.ini is the main configuration for PHP its self. Depending on your setup Laravel might be able to over ride some one these settings.

Look at http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time and http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Funning phpinfo(); will also tell you where the php.ini is located.