# PHP WSOD Apache Error

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wsod

I'm running the latest WAMP package currently. I'm trying to run OpenCart but I just get a blank white screen after I modified the Index.php a bit. I looked at the Apache error log and I cannot tell warning from error and I have no clue what to fix.

```
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:19.458060 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:19.459060 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:20.562123 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:20.591124 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1f PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:20.592124 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:20.592124 2014] [core:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:20.595125 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 16260
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:21.493176 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 16260:tid 476] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:21.494176 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 16260:tid 476] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:22.557237 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 16260:tid 476] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:22.574238 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16260:tid 476] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:47.489663 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:52.001921 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16260:tid 476] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jan 24 21:48:52.031923 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16096:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 16260 exited successfully.
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Activate error reporting so you get errors right on the screen. [How do I enable error reporting in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6575482)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes I've done that, still nothing has shown up.

Comment: Look at your `php error log` whats in there. I would start by removong your changes to `index.php` and then making them 1 at a time until you break it again. Then you will know what you did wrong.

Comment: This is an apache / SSL configuration error. I wish I could help but I'm having a similar problem, when I figure out what's wrong I'll post an answer.  Your problem is basically the distro breaking up SSL directives from the base SSL virtual host configuration. Try posting this on serverfault instead of stack exchange.