# MySQL Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: mysql

This is what I've tried, I know the syntax is wrong and there are too many brackets causing it not to work but I was just testing stuff!

Code:

```
$SQLGetLogs = $odb -> query("
    SELECT * FROM `logs` 
    WHERE (`time` + `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND `stopped` = 1)
      AND `user` = '$MyUser'
");
```

Any ideas what to do?

How will I make this query work so all the clauses are included?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Updated, sorry about that @i--.

Comment: With the code formatted, it is clearer what you are attempting. As the Boolean AND operator associates, the parenthesis in the WHERE clause are redundant, but that is not an error. What error message/condition are you seeing?

Comment: What is the value of $MyUser? Of what data type are the time & date fields?

Comment: Well there isn't essentially an error message, but it just doesn't display. If i remove the paranethesis around the first two clauses and just delete the third one it works, but I can't change any of them to OR, it has to be included as is. Not sure how to do it D:

Comment: Ill try to make it a bit more clear, the actual clauses work perfectly its just I'm trying to add a third clause to it which is "AND `stopped` = 1". How would I add it into the already working query?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the stopped field. You sure there is a field named "stopped" in logs table, spelt correctly? Also you probably need to [enable your php errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php) to see what is going on.

Comment: Already enabled php errors and no stopped is correct and everything, are you sure it has nothing to do with the setup? There are 2 and sections of the where clause.

Comment: @user3023566, as mentioned by P Geerkens, your mysql syntax is correct. How do you know that it does not work? May be it just does not return any records and your code shows nothing for such situation? Show the code that displays results.

Comment: Time + date? What's that?