# Pages returning 500 to Google, but I can always see them?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, seo

Google isn't indexing my blog, because pages in the blog are returning 500 errors. However, I'm always able to view these pages in Chrome, and when I do a curl, I see status '200'.

Here's a page that Google says is returning 500:

https://critter.co/blog/2014/01/the-iphoneipad-app-is-out/

I don't even know where to start with this, I'm completely lost. Any ideas?

Thank you,
Katie

Update: Now that I can see the 500 error myself, I've learned that several mainstream WordPress plugins - All In One SEO, Antispam Bee, Growmap Anti Spambot Plugin, WordPress HTTPS - are triggering the 500 error. I've at least got a short-term solution with deactivating those plugins. On the hunt. :)

Comment: It is indeed sending a 500 header along with the page's content for me.

Comment: Thanks, Pekka - how are you seeing that? What program/command/tool?

Comment: "Inspect Element" in Chrome -> Network tab  http://i.stack.imgur.com/CWToV.png I'd check the server logs first... it could also be a wayward module or theme or something

Comment: Ah, yay, I see it! Thank you! Being able to see if changes I make have an effect is half the battle. Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Looking at your HTML source, it's a sidebar widget that is likely failing and throwing a fatal error. (The first widget that isn't the critter widget)

Comment: Just updated this post with what I've found w/ plugins - may be a more general problem since it's affecting so many well-known plugins?

Comment: There is likely to be a specific PHP error happening in one of the widgets. If you want to investigate, you'd have to activate error reporting to see what message comes up. See [How do I enable error reporting in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6575482)

Comment: Hmm, okay, will do :) Thanks, Pekka!

Comment: Okay, this is really weird: while debugging, I added this line: ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); - and that line *itself* fixes the 500 error, with all plugins enabled as before. If I take out that line, I get the 500 error. What could be going on here?

Comment: I see this in the page's source code: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/web/servers/critter.co/htdocs/templates/_footers/default.php on line 159` that's likely the culprit