# External login verification in Joomla

Tags: php, encryption, joomla

Using code from simular questions here I am trying to login users from a game into Joomla.
My problem is that i'm not getting a positive pasword verification.

Since I was having great difficult converting my original script what worked prior joomla 3.2 with the solutions given to simular questions, I made this test script.

I created user named 'test' with a pasword 'test' and copied the encrypted pw from phpMyAmdin to the script.
According to all information I can find on Joomla and this website my pasword verification should be succesfull, but its failing.
Am I missing something or what is going on here?

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', "../public_html" );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( "instellingen.php" );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();   

// created a test username with test as password in joomla
$username   = "test";
$password   = "test";
$dbPW       = "$P$DxdrgIwlYqFE23mQjYvgvTNO3zoVN40";  // copied from phpMyAdmin
$id         = JUserHelper::getUserId($username);
echo "$id"; //<-- matches value shown in phpMyAdmin

if(JUserHelper::verifyPassword($password, $dbPW, $id))
{
    echo "succesfull Login!";
}
else
{
    echo "failed Login!";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some [**general PHP knowledge about strings variables and quotes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) and having your [**development system properly configured**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php) certainly can help you get over this kind of issues.

I hope now you have spotted your mistake.

Below is a solution that should work for you:

```
<?php
/**
 * Joomla! External authentication script
 *
 * @author vdespa
 * Version 1.0
 *
 * Code adapted from /index.php
 *
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<'))
{
    die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// JFactory
require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');


// Hardcoded for now
$credentials['username'] = 'admin';
$credentials['password'] = 'admin';

/**
 * Code adapted from plugins/authentication/joomla/joomla.php
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  Authentication.joomla
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// Get a database object
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('id, password')
    ->from('#__users')
    ->where('username=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObject();

if ($result)
{
    $match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $result->password, $result->id);

    if ($match === true)
    {
        // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
        $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id);
        var_dump($user);
        echo 'Joomla! Authentication was successful!';
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid password
        // Prmitive error handling
        die('Invalid password');
    }
} else {
    // Invalid user
    // Prmitive error handling
    die('Cound not find user in the database');
}
```

Comment: Thanks got it to work, looks like I miss some basic knowledge of php like what the different quotes do and better get that sorted now :)

Comment: wow, I must comment! this still work with joomla 3.x.x versions, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If this helps you, I think `Joomla` has an encryption algorithm which works like this:

1. You create an user `$user`
2. You assign it a password `$password`
3. Joomla! creates a pseudo random array of 32 chars from A to Z a to z and 0 to 9 and call this array `$salt`
4. Joomla! creates another variable called `$hash` concatenating your variable user with the salt and get the md5 from all of it, like this... `$hash = md5($user.$salt)`
5. Joomla! saves a password which is again a concatenation of your hash then 2 points and then the salt, in this format.... `$hash.":".$salt`
6. That's why when you check out your database your password looks like this:
   `3977807f631949e190966ae148a073ee:8z2Geal1qzizkhSTN6hP4fMrnnRxXbrj`

I try to connect my Joomla site with my php site so i try to enter into the Joomla! db, but splitting the variables to make it work, I will post the code for anyone who wants it...

## login.php

Note: the `login.php` file only does the comparison between the already existing password in joomla's db, and does not crypt it, I'll try to edit this comment with the additional file tomorrow because I have to go, also i will translate the Spanish parts, sorry I'm from Mexico xD

```
conectar();
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);     
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($contrasena);
if (isset($_POST['username']))
    {
    $pass="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($pass);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $pass=$row["password"];
    list($hash,$salt) = explode(":",$pass); //split the bd password
    $cripto = md5($mypassword.$salt); //md5 into pass+salt
    if (($hash==$cripto) && ($count==1))
        {
        echo "true";
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['idUsuario'] = $row['idUser'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
        $_SESSION['rolUser'] = $row['rol'];
        //header("location:login_success.php");
        }
    else 
    {
        echo "false";
    }
}
else 
    {
    echo "false";
    }
desconectar();
?>
```

## conexion.php

And also I show you my `conectar()` code, which only performs the connections to the db

```
<?php
function conectar(){

    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db_nombre="joomla";
    $conexion = @mysql_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$conexion) {
        die('Error in connection: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
        //echo "<div class='success'> Conectado satisfactoriamente </div>";     
        $db = @mysql_select_db($db_nombre, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
function desconectar()
{
    @mysql_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

finally, the crypter, it will be something like this:

## crypter.php

```
<?php
function pseudoRandom($values)
{
$values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
$chainNumber=$values;
$originalPassword = ""; 
for($i=0;$i<$chainNumber;$i++)
    {
    $originalPassword .= substr($values,rand(0,strlen($values)),1); 
    }
return $originalPassword;
}
$originalPassword = ’caca’;
$salt=pseudoRandom(32);
$hash=md5($cadena.$salt);
$finalPassword=$hash.”:”.$salt;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `JCryptPasswordSimple->verify($postpassword,$dbpasswordhash)`  in libraries/joomla/crypt/password/simple.php

Answer (score 0):

for a more recent version of joomla (3.x) you can use below snippet

jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );

```
// Hardcoded for now
$credentials['username'] = 'admin';
$credentials['password'] = 'admin';

//create a new password or load it from the database using the user, you might need to change the encryption method
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($credentials['password'] , $salt, 'md5-hex');
$password = $crypt.':'.$salt;


$match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $password);

if ($match === true){
    echo 'Joomla! Authentication was successful!';
}else{
    // Invalid password
    // Prmitive error handling
    die('Invalid password');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a login page which from outside of Joomla, ( I used Joomla 2.5, if you are using higher version, you can take it as a reference)

```
<?php

//this xxx.php is outside of Joomla root
//and Joomla root is in ./login folder

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', './login' );

// Required Files
require_once (JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php');

// To use Joomla's Database Class
require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');

/********* POST login data from some where *********/   
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['psw'])) {

    $credentials['username'] = trim($_POST['uname']);
    $credentials['password'] = trim($_POST['psw']);

    if(class_exists(JFactory)) {

        $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');    

        // Get a database object
        $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select('id, password');
        $query->from('#__users');
        $query->where('username=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadObject();

        if ($result)
        {
            $match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $result->password, $result->id);

            if ($match === true)
            {
                $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id); // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
                $app->login($credentials);

                echo ("This user is logged in and Joomla also logged in! ");
            }
            else
            {
                echo ("User name and password not match! ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("THE USER IS NOT REGISTERED! ");
        }
    }
} 

?>
```