# Blank php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 2 pages, one generates a bit for the job information called `jobs.php` and another page called `Jobdescription.php` displays the full details of the job I selected. On the `jobdescription.php` page, 2 tables are involved one called `Employers` and the other called `APP_Jobs`. This is the code I have got so far, but I get a blank page with no error or anything.

```
<?
    //database connection
    $dblink = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_pw, $mysqli_db);
    $sql_query = "SELECT APP_Jobs.* FROM APP_Jobs INNER JOIN Employers on APP_Jobs.Emp_id=Employers.Emp_id"; 
    $query_result = mysqli_query($dblink, $sql_query) OR die ("Cannot read from DB ".mysql_error($dblink));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query_result))
    {
        {
            echo "<h3>'".$row['Job_Title']."'</h3>";
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>
                        Employer : ".$row["Emp_name"]." <br />
                        Address : ".$row["Emp_address"]." <br />
                        Town     : ".$row["Emp_town"]." <br /><br />

                        <h1>Job Details</h1>
                        Description : ".$row["Job_description"]."<br />
                        Skills Required : ".$row["Job_Skills"]."<br />
                        Training provided : ".$row["Job_Training"]." <br /><br />
                        Start : ".$row["Job_StartDate"]."<br />
                        pay:".$row["Job_pay"]." <br /><br />

                        <a href=CV1.php?Job_id=".$row["Job_id"].">Apply</a>
                    </td>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan=\"2\"><hr size=\"1\"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>\n";
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: You might have error reporting turned off. See this answer to turn it on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Comment: does your server support short php opening tags ? `<?`

Comment: Also, just turn on error reporting in your development environment, as soon as you move your script to production turn it off. Some errors (especially db errors) could contain sensitive information that could allow an attacker to compromise your site.

Comment: @samitha good point. Instead of using `<?` use `<?php`. That's backwards compatible, and a good practice in PHP.

Comment: @samitha yeah it does...everything works alright on the first page.

Comment: @user3376648 what do you mean ?

Comment: I have reformatted your code and there are several syntax errors. If you format your code properly it will be easier for you to spot where it is going wrong.

Comment: you can still use `var_dump()`/`die()` to find where the code goes south !

Comment: @samitha this is a secondary page of a job...the first page displays a list of jobs and this displays the details about it

Answer (score 0):

There must be something going wrong in your database code.

Add the following to the top of the page to show errors:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: error_reporting is on but still doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you use samitha's comment about `<?`. Did you also check that your query returns data. If it doesn't, then there's no output (at least with this snippet of code you provided)

Answer (score 0):

There Are too many quotation marks (") in echo

try

```
     echo "<h3>'\".$row['Job_Title'].\"'</h3>";
```

and same in your below code too like

```
      echo "
         <tr>
        <td>
            Employer : \".$row['Emp_name'].\" <br />
            Address : \".$row['Emp_address'].\" <br />
            Town     : \".$row['Emp_town'].\" <br /><br />

            <h1>Job Details</h1>
            Description : \".$row['Job_description'].\"<br />
            Skills Required : \".$row['Job_Skills'].\"<br />
            Training provided : \".$row['Job_Training'].\" <br /><br />
            Start : \".$row['Job_StartDate'].\"<br />
            pay:\".$row['Job_pay'].\" <br /><br />

        <a href=CV1.php?Job_id=\".$row['Job_id'].\">Apply</a>

        </td>
        <tr><td colspan=\"2\"><hr size=\"1\"/></td></tr>
        </tr>\n";
```

Comment: thank you, i just tried your code and now i'm getting a syntax error syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on this line echo "<h3>'\".$row['Job_Title'].\"'</h3>";.

Comment: try echo "<h3>\".$row['Job_Title'].\"</h3> ";