# Function defined in include cannot be found

Tags: php, function, undefined

I have this function defined in a FileA.php

```
function readDirectory($aPath) {
    $list = Array();
    if(is_dir($aPath)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($aPath)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if(is_file("$aPath/$file") && $file != '.htaccess') {
                    $list[$file] = "$file";
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    sort($list, SORT_STRING);
    return $list;
}
```

And I got FileA.php `included()` in FileB.php and then FileB.php `included()` in the FileC.php I want
to execute. But I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function readDirectory() in ..folder/FileC.php on line 2

Can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It's clearly not being included. Make sure your path to the files are correct in your includes.

Comment: try to use a 'require' instead of 'include'. 'require' will return an error if the file wasn't found (so we can check if the problem is that). Probably your files are in different directories so you need to control your includes path

Comment: Please show us how you are including the files and please [enable *full* error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `included()` use `include()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php