# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am integrating the **jQuery-File-Upload** plugin into my php/mysqli site. I am attempting to modify the code so that when the user uploads images the user's email will be added to the database. I have added an email column to the database. My problem is when the "**Start Upload**" button is clicked it adds the images to the folders but does not update the database with any of the info. It throws an error, "**SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**" I have hunted the net with no luck and have tried multiple experiments with the code and still get the same error so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the **index.html** with the mods I did to add the email:

```
        <div class="container">

    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>

            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
    </form>
        </div>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span><br><label class="title">
    <span>Title:</span><br>
    <input name="title[]" class="form-control">
</label>
<label class="description">
    <span>Description:</span><br>
    <input name="description[]" class="form-control">
</label>
<label class="email">
    <span>Email:</span><br>
    <input name="email[]" class="form-control">
</label>

        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span><br><p class="title"><strong>{%=file.title||''%}</strong></p>
                       <p class="description">{%=file.description||''%}</p>
                       <p class="email">{%=file.email||''%}</p>

        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Here is the modified **index.php**:

```
    $options = array(
        'delete_type' => 'POST',
        'db_host' => 'localhost',
        'db_user' => 'left-out-for-public-display',
        'db_pass' => 'left-out-for-public-display',
        'db_name' => 'left-out-for-public-display',
        'db_table' => 'files'
    );

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

    protected function initialize() {
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $this->options['db_host'],
            $this->options['db_user'],
            $this->options['db_pass'],
            $this->options['db_name']
        );
        parent::initialize();
        $this->db->close();
    }

    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
        $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
        $file->email = @$_REQUEST['email'][$index];
    }

    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );
        if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`, `email`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description,
                $file->email
                            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
    }

    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description`, `email` FROM `'
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $type,
                $title,
                $description,
                $email

            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                $file->id = $id;
                $file->type = $type;
                $file->title = $title;
                $file->description = $description;
                $file->email = $email;
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete($print_response = true) {
        $response = parent::delete(false);
        foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
            if ($deleted) {
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'
                    .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
                $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $query->bind_param('s', $name);
                $query->execute();
            }
        } 
        return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
    }

}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured this out and it's working great now. I wanted to share what I found just in case somebody else does a search on this same problem.

The first problem:

In the code above for the index.php:

```
$query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
```

This won't fly because I've added a string but I forgot to add another s.

This code is now changed to:

```
$query->bind_param(
                    'sissss', //Added an s
```

I can't take any credit for this solution and I owe a big thank you to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712069/tom-mcgee who provided my solution over at [Add more custom variables to mysql insert on blueimp/jquery-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517699/add-more-custom-variables-to-mysql-insert-on-blueimp-jquery-file-upload)

The second problem: Totally **self-inflicted** but I digress...

In the UploadHandler.php there is a piece of code like this:

```
 protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        // Handle form data, e.g. $_POST['description'][$index]
           }
```

Yours truly changed that code to this:

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
$_POST['email'][$index]
               }
```

Once I returned this code back to the original form everything is good to go. I reckon having this function duplicated in two different files was not a proper approach.

I would like to compliment Sebastian Tschan on this jQuery File Upload. It's very excellent and very free. If you are looking for a good upload handler you can find Mr. Tschan on GitHub at https://github.com/blueimp