# error check in PHP using php function

Tags: php

I saw various docs and threads, there are various function to do it.
I put error in my code and tried those functions. But it does not show what is error and where it is.

Can some one please show me how they are to be used?

For example:

```
<?php
error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

i
echo "testing"
?>
```

Above code has two error one is undefine `i` and another ';' missing. How to I see these error?

Comment: You're not seeing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in 'file location' on line 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable error reporting in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

To show `php errors`, add this one at the top of your page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Can you please show me example on ideone, I added it but no help http://ideone.com/1nHyyu

Comment: @Programming_crazy I don't think, why you are putting `i` before `echo 'testing'`. Actually `error_reporting` throws only the `logical error`, not a `syntax error`. [Check out here](http://ideone.com/rwV9ne)

Comment: @Check: thanks for this. IS there any way to check syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all PHP errors reported then use..

```
error_reporting(-1)
```

Heres a link to the manual for [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Dude function name I alraedy know, how and where to use that the issue

Comment: you need to add it at the top of your php page. I have added an example here https://gist.github.com/maskaravivek/10462711

Comment: thanks, does it check syntax error? is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

use error_reporting(-1)            //This will report all types of php error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Exception Handler using `set_error_handler('exceptionHandler function');`

Here is what is use

```
if (!function_exists('exceptionHandler')) {

    function exceptionHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line)
    {
        if ($severity == E_STRICT) {
            return;
        }
        // code logic to handle or display exceptions
    }
}
```

This would be the way you can have control over handling exceptions.

Comment: So I need to write everything in this sort of function?

Comment: just code to handle a 404 exception, file_exists or whatever logic you want to build in