# Php script on localhost

Tags: php, github

Hey guys i have installed php,xampp and its working well.When i tried to execute a php script from github in localhost its showing me a blank page..

The script is https://github.com/super3/IRC-Bot/#run

I have tested it in my webserver and it works well..But when i downloaded those files and tested on my localhost its giving me a blank page.

Hope you guys can help me ..Any help would be appreciated..Sorry if this is a low grade question on so.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What kind of output on the screen are you expecting? How are you running the script? Are you just navigating to the script in your url bar?

Comment: do you have the dependancy installed?  what are the logs saying?  make sure php is set to display errors, and paste them here - without that, we don't have much to go on.

Comment: am expecting a chat like screen ..Its a chat app in php ....but instead of that i get a blank page ..i have navigated to localhost/mainfile.php..Main file is the index file on the whole script ..

Comment: Have a look at the error logs. There should be a php one. Alternatively set php errors to on in your script temporarily. That gives us a starting point.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php That should enable displaying errors.

Comment: @flauntster what do you mean by dependancy here ??

Comment: @user3534308, sorry i just noticed the dependancy is optional.. on the github page, it mentions a dependancy - proctitle

Comment: Looks like your XAMP probably does not have one or more PHP extensions enabled that the app requires. You should change your error reporting first of all, a blank screen is not very useful.

Comment: @flauntster i didnt get what you mean by dependancy ??..can you explain me whats it ..proctitle ??..whats that too ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you may want to check is your php.ini file to make sure your display_errors and display_startup_errors are turned on. if they aren't or they don't exist, put them in and then restart your server.