# PHP file not working

Tags: php, mysql

I’m making a practice website for signing in, using PHP and MySQL. However, when I click submit, the PHP doesn't execute and get data from my database, but it is opened. I can’t seem to find what's wrong in my coding. I have checked and php is enabled and interpreted.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Sign-In</title>
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sign-in">
<fieldset style="width:30%"><legend>Sign In Here</legend>
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php">
Username<br><input type="text" name="username" size="40"><br><br>
Password<br><input type="password" name="password" size="40"><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my php file:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'databasename');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
/*
$ID = $_POST['username'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];
*/

function SignIn()
    {
    session_start();
    if (!empty($_POST['username']))
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT* FROM Username WHERE username ='$_POST[username]' AND password ='$_POST[password]'", $db) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if (!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password']))
            {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];
            echo "Successfully Signed In.";
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Sorry, you entered the wrong username and password. Please Try Again.";
            }
        }
    }

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    SignIn();
    }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I'm using the tutorial from [this website](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-login-page-with-php-and-mysql/28656), but have different names. I'm pretty new at this, so when answering please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Besides that, you may want to [adjust the error reporting to see all errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6575482/53114).

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: try adding error reporting to your php file: ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I would recommend, https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system tutorial! The one you are following, seems pretty old..

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? because you have a small error in your query. `SELECT*` should be `SELECT *`

Comment: @Gil That isn't really the error, SQL interprets it correctly even though it's safe to leave a space. @OP: Can you check if your function is being called first of all? `echo` anything inside your function before the `if`s.

Comment: may be this will resolve this issue, Replace this define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'); line with define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

Comment: thanks, I changed the query line as suggested underneath and used mysqli instead. when I used mysqli, it said "failed to connect to mysql'. so does that mean something is wrong with my connection code? if so, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `mysql_query` try

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT* FROM Username WHERE username =" . $_POST['username'] . "AND password ="._POST['password'],$db) or die(mysql_error($con));
```

You should use the `.` operator to concatenate strings. And you forgot the quotes in `$_POST[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is the missing quotes.

This:

```js
$query= mysql_query ("SELECT* FROM Username WHERE username ='$_POST[username]' AND password ='$_POST[password]'",$db) or die (mysql_error());
```

Should probably be this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Username WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}' AND password = '{$_POST['password']}'",$db) or die (mysql_error());
```

**And a couple of other things**

- Mysql_ is deprecated as of 5.5, use mysqli_ or PDO instead.
- Filter user input to avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- Check out [prepared statements.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: thanks, when I used mysqli, it said "failed to connect to mysql'. so does that mean something is wrong with my connection code? if so, what?

Comment: mysqli_ is not the same as mysql_, so you'll have to change all of your database related code to use mysqli instead. But you can still use mysql. Just keep in mind that mysql_ is outdated and **should not be used in new projects**. Feel free to stick with mysql_ **for learning**, it's probably a bit easier since most of the **older books and tutorials** still uses it. Feel free to mark my answer as the solution if it was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both strings and varibles like `"My name is $name"`, there are some ways o do it.

1. Collecting strings with variables containing numbers and strings:

   - `$var = 'My name is' . $name;`
   - `$var = "My name is" . $name;`
   - `$var = "My name is $name";`
   - **Note:**
     `$var = 'My name is $name;'` won't output the `$name` *value*, but its *name*.
2. Collecting strings with variables containing arrays:

   - `$var = 'My name is' . $user['name'];`
   - `$var = "My name is" . $user['name'];`
   - `$var = "My name is {$user['name']}";`
     Without the `{}` brackets this won't work properly.

That's why this line:

```
$query = mysql_query("... username ='$_POST[username]' AND password ='$_POST[password]'", $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

should be replaced with this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Username WHERE username ='".$_POST['username']."' AND password ='".$_POST['password']."'", $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

or this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Username WHERE username = \"{$_POST['username']}\" AND password = \"{$_POST['password']}\"", $db) or die(mysql_error());
```