# How to use || in function

Tags: php

I have a function that checks user permissions and I want it to do this:

```
if(verify("O") || ("M"))
```

so that it checks if the user has the permission "O" or "M" but it does not work

Comment: As well as looking at the duplicate question you should also at least check for obvious errors before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Comment: @Joe This actually isn't a duplicate, contrary to popular belief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. This should work:

```
if(verify("O") || verify("M"))
```

If your function **verify()** only accepts one input. You need to call it again with the second input. Now, if either **verify("O")** or **verify("M")** returns true, your IF statement will return true.

Comment: Edited my answer with an explaination.

Comment: I was gonna, then it told me i had to wait, so i got a few things done... I accepted it as  the answer now though