# PHP webservice error

Tags: php, web-services, webserver

Hi I have a webservice that requires a database handler class when a request is received. Everything works perfectly when run and tested locally but when I hosted the service on a server these two lines cause an issue:

```
    //Require database functions
    require_once 'Functions.php';
    $db = new Functions();
```

For some reason it can't seem to access the class even though they are all in the same directory.

Anyone have any ideas to what might be causing this?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Try `require_once('Functions.php');`

Comment: Provide some output please. What is the error message you get ?

Comment: It doesn't give any output, the page is just blank

Comment: Enable error reporting so you can get error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php#6575502

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54342/discussion-between-athanasios-emmanouilidis-and-dermot).

Comment: Thanks Athanasios I got it, I had a variable set to private instead of var

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it.