# Outlook API - We received a bad request

Tags: php, oauth, outlook, outlook-restapi

I'm following [this](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php) tutorial exactly and am getting the following message: Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.  Miserably, Microsoft isn't giving me anything other than that message.

EDIT: here is the code I'm using with the ID's and passwords masked

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require('oauth.php');

$loggedIn = false;
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost:9999/outlook_cal03/authorize.php';
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Mail API Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        if (!$loggedIn) {
    ?>
            <!-- User not logged in, prompt for login -->
            <p>Please <a href="<?php echo oAuthService::getLoginUrl($redirectUri)?>">sign in</a> with your Office 365 or Outlook.com account.</p>
            <?php
        }
        else {
            ?>
            <!-- User is logged in, do something here -->
            <p>Hello user!</p>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

oauth.php

```
<?php
class oAuthService {
    private static $clientId = "###################";
    private static $clientSecret = "################";
    private static $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
    private static $authorizeUrl = '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%1$s&redirect_uri=%2$s&response_type=code&scope=%3$s';
    private static $tokenUrl = "/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";

    // The app only needs openid (for user's ID info), and Mail.Read
    private static $scopes = array("openid", "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read");

    public static function getLoginUrl($redirectUri) {

        $redirectUri = $redirectUri;

        // Build scope string. Multiple scopes are separated
        // by a space
        $scopestr = implode(" ", self::$scopes);

        $loginUrl = self::$authority.sprintf(self::$authorizeUrl, self::$clientId, urlencode($redirectUri), urlencode($scopestr));

        error_log("Generated login URL: ".$loginUrl);
        return $loginUrl;
    }
}
?>
```

authorize.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$auth_code = $_GET['code'];
?>

<p>Auth code: <?php echo $auth_code ?></p>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for php? Can you update the answer with the code that you have tried ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 - added the code.

Comment: Error reporting on? Are you getting any error messages ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php

Comment: @Maximus2012 Error reporting is completely turned on.  No errors in PHP.  Do you have experience with Outlook API?

Comment: Not really but if you are following the tutorial correctly then it is possible that the error could be at the PHP end which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Did you look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2615736 ?

Answer (score 1):

My problems all stemmed from the fact that I had failed to register my redirect URL with Outlook, and that was it.

Comment: I was killing myself over this, and now the answer is so simple I feel like an idiot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line and it will work:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation? How does changing the error reporting level make code work?